# How can I get the value of data attribute in jQuery from an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I´m new to jQuery and i need help with this...

I have this html:

```
<div class="portfolio__items">
          <div class="portfolio__item">
            <img src="./img/web-1.jpg" id="img1" alt="Imagen Web de Ejemplo 1" />
            <div class="portfolio__btns">
              <a href="#!" class="portfolio__btn prev" data-id="img1"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>  Preview</a>
              <a href="#!" class="portfolio__btn"><i class="fab fa-github"></i>  Github</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="portfolio__item">
            <img src="./img/web-2.jpg" id="img2" alt="Imagen Web de Ejemplo 2" />
            <div class="portfolio__btns">
              <a href="#!" class="portfolio__btn prev" data-id="img2"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i>  Preview</a>
              <a href="#!" class="portfolio__btn"><i class="fab fa-github"></i>  Github</a>
            </div>
          </div>
```

...etc...etc...

And this jQuery:

```
function cambiaImagenes(items) {
    var self = this;
    log("Valor self:")
    log(self)
    var portfolio = $(items);
    log("Valor portfolio:")
    log(portfolio)
    var botones = portfolio.find("div.portfolio__item");
    log("Valor botones:")
    log(botones)
       
    function swap_modal(a) {
      el = this;
      log(el) 
      value = el.data("id");
      log(value)
    }
    botones.on("click", "a.prev", swap_modal);
  }
  new cambiaImagenes("div.portfolio__items");
```

And I get this result in the console:

```
Valor self:
cambiaImagenes {}

Valor portfolio:
S.fn.init [div.portfolio__items, prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]

Valor botones:
S.fn.init(6) [div.portfolio__item, div.portfolio__item, div.portfolio__item, div.portfolio__item, div.portfolio__item, div.portfolio__item, prevObject: S.fn.init(1)]


<a href=​"#!" class=​"portfolio__btn prev" data-id=​"img1">​…​</a>​
Uncaught TypeError: el.data is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.swap_modal (main.js:216)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.patchedCallback (<anonymous>:132:45)


<a href=​"#!" class=​"portfolio__btn prev" data-id=​"img2">​…​</a>​
Uncaught TypeError: el.data is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.swap_modal (main.js:216)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.v.handle (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDivElement.patchedCallback (<anonymous>:132:45)
```

As you can see, each time i click on a link with the data-id attribute, it gives me the correct link back with the event, but i´m unable to get the value of data("id").

What I´m doing wrong??

Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for 
`let yourval = $(el).attr('data-id');`

Comment: @Voriann, You can use the `dataset` property. Try `el.dataset.id` and if you want to jQuery then use `$(el).data('id')`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this example  help you

```js
//get all data from form 
 let data_form_attr = {};
 $.each($('#form').find(':input'), function (index, ref) {
            const element = $(ref);
            
            console.log("value of "+ element.attr('data-attr')+": "+element.val());
           
        });
        
 //get from attr from any tag
  let value= $('#h1_id').attr('data-attr');
 console.log (value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<!-- form  -->
<form  id="form">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text"   data-attr='fname'  id="fname" name="fname" value="John"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" data-attr='lname'   id="lname"  name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
</form> 



<!-- any tag  -->
<h1 data-attr='data attribute' id="h1_id" class="form-control">
```